# is this a correct way of designing a filter?

Tags: matlab, filter

i use filter like this, i have no idea whether it is a right way.
If **filter** function in the last line replaced by **filtfilt** ,then there will be some *zeros in my out's edge*. and is the filtfilt's output *zerophase*?
Based on its output , i think it is,while the filter function's output is not .

```
function [grpdly,out] = myflt(fs,f2,f1,order,data)
Fs = fs;  % Sampling Frequency
N    = order;      % Order
Fc1  = 1/f1;%  % First Cutoff Frequency
Fc2  = 1/f2;     % Second Cutoff Frequency
flag = 'scale';  % Sampling Flag
% Create the window vector for the design algorithm.
win = hamming(N+1);
% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
[b,a] = fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);
% Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
out=filtfilt(b,a,data);
grpdly = grpdelay(b,a);
```

---

```
s=mysignal;
[gd,out] = myflt(1,30,60,100,s);
```

i use it like this, the out has no  zeros padded in two edges ,and the gd is 100. Is there any problems?

Comment: What are you actually asking? From `help filtfilt`: 
`filtfilt Zero-phase forward and reverse digital IIR filtering.` So yes it is zerophase.

Comment: @Jørgen, but i use the **fir1** function get b & a, so is there any problems in my code?

Comment: there is no problem using `fir1`, it is a perfectly normal way to do it. How you apply the filter, using the coefficients in `a` and `b` is up to you and your requirements. So either use `filter` or `filtfilt`.